# ngFor update after object has changed?

Tags: angular

I have a function that updates an object property when item has been dropped in drag and drop. Either because my function is wrong, or there is something else I have to do it seams this is not working. The display does not update

```
onItemDrop(event: any) {
    const dropId = event.nativeEvent.srcElement.id;
    const dropItem = event.dragData;
    const update = this.results.find(item => {
        return item.storyFunnelStatusId === dropItem.storyFunnelStatusId;
    });
    update.storyFunnelStatusId = dropId;
    this.results = this.results;
}
```

and then this should update:

`<div class="card bg-light-blue mb-2" *ngFor="let item of (results | groupBy: column.id)" [dragData]="item" draggable></div>`

Comment: Why do you have `this.results = this.results;` in the last line?

Comment: yea i was just trying to update the dsplay so i through that in there to see if that would work. In threory it should not be needed right?

Comment: You are never changing your results array

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing, but `this.results` was not being updated. You create `update` and didn't do anything with it, neither `this.results`

Comment: shouldn't `update.storyFunnelStatusId = dropId;` be effecting the results object? but you are right...when I console `update` i see the new value, however when I console `results` the value has not been effected. hat am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `this.results.find` returns a new array which is not bonded with `this.results`. So any changes in `update` will not affect `this.results`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: find the element index and change it directly in `this.results`.

```
onItemDrop(event: any) {
    const dropId = event.nativeEvent.srcElement.id;
    const dropItem = event.dragData;
    // find the updated element index
    const index = this.results.findIndex(item => {
        return item.storyFunnelStatusId === dropItem.storyFunnelStatusId;
    });
    this.results[index].storyFunnelStatusId = dropId;
    // this.results = this.results;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... does `console.log(index)` return anything?

Comment: yes it returns `4` however strange index does not match the index if this results that should actually be effected.

Comment: What do you want to do with the dropped element? Remove from `this.results` -> `this.results.splice(index, 1)`?

Comment: so for example where i am at now, i am logging results before we perform the find. the index of the item that is being dragged is 6 at this stage. then we set `index find etc...` and then we log index it is returning 4 when it should be 6

Comment: then i need to change the value of it's item.storyFunnelStatusId so that the diplay uupdates and moves the item to the correct column

Comment: ok so i have your code above working, but I had to use a  different property to compare against. now when I log this.results, the item has the correct value. However the display is not updating.

Comment: Now, what about your `groupBy: column.id` pipe? Does it get the change in `this.results`?

Comment: yes it filters `results` by by matching a column id to thestoryFunnelStatusId